# extract the file name from the directory

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. I wrote a code to import data from a text file part of it is prompting the user to choose a file to open. my question is how to extract the file name and save it in a cell or even assign it to a variable let's say X.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ChDir "C:\Users\majed502\Documents\VBA WORK\VBA"
    
   the_file_picked = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
        
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        the_file_picked, Origin:=437, _
        StartRow:=4, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11 _
        , 1), Array(23, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(53, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
    'Sheets("Nov2007").Select
    ActiveSheet.Move Before:=Workbooks("monthly update.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    
    Rows("1:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 7)

End Sub
```

I'm currently taking the name out of the sheet name but would like to take it from the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the filename from an entire path, you might do like in following macro:

```
Sub test()
Dim a As String
a = "C:\Temp_Folder\blabla.txt"

iSplit = InStrRev(a, "\")

strName = Right(a, Len(a) - iSplit)
End Sub
```

=> `strName` equals "blabla.txt", which is the filename.

As a oneliner, you can go for this here:

```
strName = Right(str_Path, Len(str_Path) - InStrRev(str_Path, "\"))
```

... where `strPath` is the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sub.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile, FolderPath As String
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    StrFile = Dir(FolderPath & "\")  'Dir("c:\testfolder\*test*") --- Dir("C:\Users\HARUN\Music\*.xlsx")
    
    Set StartCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a cell to put file names. ", Type:=8)
    
    i = StartCell.Row
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        'Debug.Print StrFile
        Cells(i, StartCell.Column) = StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

- This will prompt user to select a folder.
- Then will prompt to select a cell to put files name.
- Modify the codes as needed.

Comment: you see this last two lines

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 7)

I just want to change the last to extract the name form the directory instead of the sheet name